# My Keyboard Broke

Tags: story

*Hey guys, I've been into brainteasers since I was little and recently decided to make a puzzle-related website. I figured that this will be the best place to share some of my problems and see if they are any fun. I guess they are too easy, but hope that will entertain you for a bit.*

> **Perfect Day**
>
> This morning I woke up at 9 o'clock. My first job was to drink a glass
>   of water and brush my teeth. After that I ate an apple, 3 bananas (I
>   love them!) and a toast with almond butter for breakfast. Then I went
>   to gym for one hour, took a shower there and came back home at eleven.
>   Cooked few pieces of chicken with some small potatoes for lunch, ate
>   all of them. In the afternoon I started working on my projects while
>   listening to classical music. In the evening I went for the 2nd time
>   to the gym, did cardio for half-an-hour and after that visited my
>   friend's apartment. We had together one big pizza for dinner and at
>   the end I fell asleep on his couch. As you can see, my entire day was
>   perfect, except that my laptop keyboard broke. Can you figure out
>   what's wrong with it?

*P.S. Please, let me know if you have seen identical puzzle elsewhere, don't want to take someone's credit, even accidentally.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be..

> The number one (1) key is broken since you had to spell out one and eleven where you used actual numbers in other places.

Comment: But what about the !?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that

> the letter Q is broken

Because

> You use every letter but Q in your puzzle

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment:) Even though you are on the right track, there is a little bit more convincing answer.